# DOCUMENT_ROOT is not complete, missing domain folder

Tags: php, document-root

I have searched many threads so far but cant seem to find a solution. Inside one of my php scripts I am trying to get a server document root but the value I get is not complete, its simply missing the domain folder. I believe it is due to sharing hosting or smth else.

Here is the current way I am using:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

and the path I get is like:

```
/home/content/01/0151247/html
```

although I know it should be like:

```
/home/content/01/0151247/html/mydomain
```

I know as I compared it with SCRIPT_NAME and I see the mydomain there in the path.

Hope someone could direct me.

Thank you and sorry for probably asking another thousand time same question over community, I really tried things around from here, nothing helps me so far.

**UPDATE**

unfortunately I cant not simply use my index file with **DIR** as it is a wordpress setup and I am working on a separate folder where I am including some wordpress functionality but for that I need a document_root. If that would help.

**UPDATE**

apparantly the following way resolved my case, maybe it will help someone one day:

```
realpath($_SERVER["SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

basically because of the server setup and domain configured as a subdomain.

Thanks to all who participated.

Comment: It would help if you gave a more full explanation of the requirements and constraints. Which files need to know the webroot and where are they located, etc.  Side Note: The value inside `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` **_is_** your document root. The document root is not always the web root.

Comment: I apologize for lack of details due to my beginner level of php and server sider programming in general. Did my best anyway. A big thanks to @Shad as I did learn quite a few things tonight! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks ;). If you find something yourself that works, go ahead and submit it as an answer to your question and accept it =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.3 you can put a file in the directory whose path you want and define a constant:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ));
```

After 5.3 you can just do:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

The idea being that this would be in `config.php` of some sort that is included every time the application runs.

[Magic Constants Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: This is clean and beautiful, but unfortunatly I am under wordpress install. I have a custom script inside my theme for so reason I can not simply use __FILE__ as I probably have no way to include that at first level with index.

Comment: @Alex what does your `ABSPATH` constant resolve to? (after including the WP bootstrap)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. If i got you right, I tried to include wp bootstrap like that require_once("/home/content/01/0151247/html/mydomain/wp-load.php"); and then echo ABSPATH; In that case I do get returned the correct path /home/content/01/0151247/html/mydomain as needed. Did that help?

Comment: @Alex Can you rely on `ABSPATH` instead of `DOCUMENT_ROOT`? Since you are including WP functionality, perhaps you could rely on WP's Constant in this case~?

Comment: Yes I could but i can get it only if I manually type in the document_root to wp-load.php and I cant afford it as it will change on other servers.

Comment: @Alex I think I need more info =)

Comment: Great News! Just found a solution. realpath($_SERVER["SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);  perfectly returns what is needed. I saw it on phpinfo(); Please confirm if that makes sense and safe to use?

Comment: @Alex If you are always going to use the same server setup then go ahead, but I've never seen that _SERVER var before myself.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

In the config file, you can just append the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mydomain';
```

And that should take care of it for you.

**Old Solution**

The `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is an environment variable set by the server. So if this is on shared hosting, you cannot changed. An alternative is to set your own constant to it, so in a `config` type file that is included on your pages you can do something like:

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mydomain');
```

And then just use that constant in place of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. The other option is to contact your host and inquire about it, maybe it was an oversight on their part and they will fix it.

**EDIT**

Probably using the `__DIR__` as others have posted about is the better way, as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` can be set to different items and at least with the `__DIR__` you should get an accurate directory each time.

Comment: unfortunately I cant not simply using my index file with __DIR__ as it is a wordpress setup and I am working on a separate folder inside the domain from inside which I am including some wordpress functionality but for that I need a document_root

Comment: @Alex Well you can just modify the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable. Updated my answer.

Comment: Actually to manually define '/mydomain' in the string is also not an option as it my change tomorrow :(

Comment: @Alex, If the `__FILE__` echos our the right directory you need, then just do `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);` and that should work out pretty good.

Comment: in my case __FILE__ returns the directly where the script is located. I dont have any include to refer to index page. Would it still be possible to detect the root in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, to get the root of a folder in PHP, I use this in the my index file:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));     // __DIR__ will work under PHP 5.3
```